# Parsing text with Unique Acronyms

Tags: java, parsing, text, text-parsing

I'm trying to work out the best method to parse scientific documents. A number of these documents contain author created unique acronyms (such as PBC = Peripheral Blood Cell, or MDI = Multiple Daily Injections).

Usually these appear in text so that the first incidence of the abbreviated term is followed by the acronym in brackets:

> "To investigate the effect of 1 year treatment with sensor-augmented
>   insulin pump (SAP) or multiple daily injections (MDI) on albuminuria"

The same text uses these acronyms and so I'm trying to get my code to recognise these and then substitute the abbreviated terms for their subsequent occurrences within the document.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You describe what you're trying to do, but you're not pointing a specific issue (you're not even saying you're having one), you're not asking a question. Do you have a question? If so, please rephrase, and provide some code for us to understand the problem you have.

Comment: I would look for all-caps words between parentheses (SAP), count the number of letters (N = 3), go back for at least N words and at most N + x words until I find a word starting with the first letter (sensor). The x offset is useful to handle things like "United States of America (USA)". This wouldn't work for "extensible markup language (XML)" for example, but then you can just leave it as is, or take exactly N words before the acronym. Anyway, you'll have to use hueristics and can't really expect the algorithm to always work.

Comment: @JBNizet SOund Navigation And Ranging?

Comment: @JBNizet or even Hypertext Transfer Protocol.

Comment: @DavidWallace As I said, heuristics are needed to try finding the appropriate words. Mayby N +/- x is better than N + x.